# Dataview inline button to update list

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a requirement of creating a custom dataview or webpart with inline button to update a list. Not sure if its totally doable using dataview or webpart will be the ultimate solution? Each row will have color status indicator and a droplist where user can select name and pass the value on Assign button to execute list update.

Help will be appreciated. TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doable in a ListView WebPart using SP2013 CSR (Client Side Rendering) and DisplayTemplates or .. a bit of hack.. stuff HTML and JavaScript in a Calculated Column (which can work in 2010 as well)

Proof of Concept:
https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/Priority

[image]

Comment: Great. Is there an option to add inline dropdownlist?